# How to create true color animated GIF from a list of BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, animation, gif, bufferedimage, animated-gif

I had a good experience with [GifSequenceWriter](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/), however it seems it does not generate true color GIF animations, but is limited to a 256 colors palette. I have a list of frames which a large variance of the color spaces, and I need a true color GIF animation.

What is the best way to achieve this, without external software?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#True_color) it does seem like it's possible

> A GIF image can include multiple image blocks, each of which can have its own 256-color palette, and the blocks can be tiled to create a complete image.

GitSequenceWriter uses `javax.imageio.ImageIO` which internally seems to be using  `com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageWriter`. But the `GIFImageWriter` instance in atleast Oracle JDK8 Installation looks like you can't have more than 8 bits to store the color palette, which restricts the number of colors to 256. You should be able to see that yourself in your Java IDE.

Comment: Thanks. Are you familiar with a solution other than ```GIFImageWriter```?

Comment: Sorry, I have not heard of anything else.